# Seeking Chesapeake Bay Watershed Boundary Shapefile?

Tags: data, united-states

Does anyone have the shapefile that depicts the boundary of the Chesapeake Bay Watershed?

I have looked through countless GDB's from government agencies without any success.

Comment: How big is the watershed? If it's large enough, you can use Hydrosheds' HydroBASINS level-12 product and select all the subwatersheds that comprise the CB Watershed. Not sure what level of detail you want.

Comment: Stack Exchange isn't a forum or a chat room. The goal is to provide the best possible answers to the best possible questions. I invite you to check out the tour: https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was on the page of the second link of a "chesapeake bay watershed shapefile" google search:

https://water.usgs.gov/GIS/dsdl/sir2005-5073_shed_shape.zip

Answer (score 1):

The repository hasn't been updated in 5 years, but this GitHub repo has a lot of Chesapeake Bay Shapefiles, GeoJson and TopoJson:
https://github.com/jalbertbowden/chesapeake-bay-data